# Sequence of results from MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I have a database for my 6-aside football team going back 10 years which is fairly normalised, so I can pull lots of stats from it for players, eg number of games played, goals scored, average points per game by player etc. 
I want to add a new stats page for sequences, eg longest run of consecutive clean sheets for goalies, longest run of consecutive wins for the team, longest run scoring in consecutive games etc.
The important tables are 'fixtures' (containing amongst others fixtureid, scorefor, scoreagainst) and 'played' (containing amongst others playerid, fixtureid, goalsscored). So to see who scored in fixture 128 I would use

```
SELECT playerid, goalsscored 
FROM played p
WHERE p.fixtureid = 128 AND goalsscored > 0
```

So how would I form a query showing which player scored in most consecutive games, eg Alex (playerid 15) scored in 6 consecutive games (fixtureid 126-132) and Dave (playerid 12) scored in 5 consecutive games (fixtureid 130-135)? Initially we can assume that fixtureid is sequential without breaks and is the order in which games were played.
I have used Sql for quite a while, but stumped by this one and I can't find any similar questions asked before.
In response to a request for more info I have added an EER diagram.
[image]

Comment: can you show us the structure of your table(s).

Comment: how are "consecutive" games set? are they consecutive by date, or by game id in the table? How will the process know that any two games are consecutive?

Comment: So there are only two teams?

Comment: ... or you only store the stats for your team

Comment: I'm only holding stats for my team. I initially created the web site 10 years ago mainly to keep tabs on players' payments. I pay for the pitch and they pay me their share, but they often forget and say "I'll pay you next week" or give me a tenner and I don't have change etc. Also to practice web site programming (I'd done C/C++/SqlServer for many years before). I'll see if I can get a table structure, though I thought I had givien enough for the question. Consecutive games should be selected by fixture date, though in practice fixtureid will give the same sequence, but may have the odd gap

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, or request for more info. I would have thought selecting sequences of rows matching certain column values is a fairly general principle. Eg a 'coinflipped' table with a 'flipid' index column and a 'isheads' column indicating heads/tails. Find the longest sequence of consecutive heads or tails.

Comment: StackOverflow encourages correspondents to answer their own questions, so feel free. Equally, many contributors to this site are happy (and perhaps even relish the opportunity) to answer questions where information is scarce, so alternatively, sit tight. Personally, I think it's more considerate to provide a representative data set (of relevant tables only) as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements, and a corresponding desired result. That's how to get my upvote.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, I have added the EER diagram above; I can add the create table definitions if that would be helpful.

Comment: I can't tell you what to do, but had a proper data set (an sqlfiddle and/or set of CREATE and INSERT statements) been provided at the outset, TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT, then this question would have been answered 5 hours ago - and with considerably less verbiage than has transpired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in code.

```
Create an List of keyvalue pairs 'CompletedSequences' - key=playerid, value=consecutivagamesscored
Create a similar List of keyvalue pairs 'CurrentSequences'
Select the list of fixtures ordered by date, omitting postponed
For each fixtureid {
   For each kv pair in CurrentSequences {
      If playerid didn't score in this fixture {   /* End of sequence for this kv */
          Add kv pair to CompletedSequences if count > 1   /* Only bother saving those with at least 2 in a sequence */
          Remove kv pair from CurrentSequences
      }
   For each scorer in this fixture {
      If playerid key exists in CurrentSequences increment count /* Add 1 to sequence */
      else create new CurrentSequences kv pair with playerid/1  /* Create new start of sequence for this player */
   }
For each kv pair in CurrenSequences  /* Finish off the ones left unterminated */
   Add kv pair to CompletedSequences if value > 1
Sort CompletedSequencies by value (consecutive games scored)
Make a table of the top 10 sequences with player/count of consecutive games scored.
```

I can't help feeling that some clever SQL script would do this better and I would prefer not to have to suck the whole resultset into memory to do it in PHP if I can avoid it. I guess I'll have do it that way if there isn't a way in MySQL.